# Checking if my acrostic poem has incorrect input

Tags: python

I'm working on a program where you need to input a topic word to use for an acrostic poem. No matter what I seem to try, I can't get a certain part of my code to work.

```
topic = input("State your topic word for an acrostic poem! (single letters do not work: ")
finalResult = "This is your poem! \n"

while True:
   try:
      float(topic)
      topic = input("That is not wholly a word!: ")
   except ValueError:
      break

for t in topic:
    if t != topic:
        poem = input(t.upper() + "(write whole words): " + "") + " \n"

        while True:
            for t in topic:
                if t != topic:
                   poem = input("That did not match your word! " + t.upper() + ":" + " ") + " \n"
                else:
                   break

     finalResult += poem

print(finalResult)
```

The part that I'm getting stuck on is the `while true` part near the end. I've gotten a bit of feedback from friends that this first iteration will just end up repeating it endlessly, because `t` will never equal to `topic`. I've also tried doing it with lists (unfortunately I lost the document that had the list version).

```
State your topic word for an acrostic poem! (single letters do not work: Love
L(write whole words): Look
That did not match your word! L: Look
That did not match your word! O: 
That did not match your word! V: 
That did not match your word! E: 
That did not match your word! L: 
That did not match your word! O: 
That did not match your word! V: 
That did not match your word! E: 
That did not match your word! L: 
That did not match your word! O: 
That did not match your word! V: 
That did not match your word! E: 
That did not match your word! L: 
That did not match your word! O: 
That did not match your word! V: 
That did not match your word! E:
```

This is an example of what happens with the above code. A similar thing happens with the list version, only it will only come up with the letter L.

```
if t != topic[0:]:
    blahblahblah repeat code
```

The above is sort of what I was trying to do - I was hoping that by transferring the string into a list, I could compare with the first letter of each sentence, and check if it was the correct one. Is there a proper way I can actually do this?

The expected input is any single word, for example: love

```
State your topic word for an acrostic poem! (single letters do not work: Love
L (write whole words): Looking for love and kindness
O (write whole words): Overly caring and affectionate
V (write whole words): Varying degrees of compassion
E (write whole words): Ending in a lovely relationship
Looking for love and kindness
Overly caring and affectionate
Varying degrees of compassion
Ending in a lovely relationship
```

This is the expected output, or at least something along those lines. My issue is that I'm trying to have it so that if I input an incorrect letter (for example: the L in love), it will say that did not match your word, and make you re-input it.

Comment: can you please provide an input and expected output? I can't figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. You enter a word like 'look'. And then you have to enter a word that begins with the letter? like I 'Love' then i would have to enter the words laughter, optimism, value, energy? something like that? and if you get it wrong is throws an error and you have to try again?

Comment: What are the loop and `float(topic)` for? As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: @AMC - Oh, sorry! I'll start doing that :] And, the float(topic) actually checks if the topic word is either an integer (1, 3, 87) or a float value (1.5, 7.89). Without it, it would allow those kinds of numbers into the program.

Comment: Oop, I forgot to say that it only checks if it is a float because of the 'try' block and the exception of the ValueError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code produces your expected output

```
# Insure topic is capitalized (i.e. applying function upper())
topic = input("State your topic word for an acrostic poem! (single letters do not work: ").upper()
finalResult = "This is your poem! \n"

for t in topic:
  while True:
    # Insure first letter of phrase is capitalized
    poem = input(t.upper() + "(write whole words): " + "").capitalize()

    if poem[0] == t:              # check that first letter matches topic
      finalResult += poem + '\n'  # Append to final result
      break                       # okay so break loop for current letter
    else:
      print(f'Phrase should beging with letter {t}')  # issue warning and try again

print(finalResult)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch DarryIG!  You're a lad!

Comment: @UbuCheese--glad I could help.  The tricky part was figuring out what was meant by an acrostic poem.

Comment: Yeah... sorry about that :{}